How to change background colour on nav bar element when it is active?
I tried solving this first using online resources. I couldn't manage to figure it out. I'm just looking to make a nav bar's background colour change when I click on it and it is active once the new page loads.
A couple of solutions that made the most sense to me but I couldn't figure out how to implement.
Javascript:
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}

jQuery:
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul.navbar-nav > li').click(function (e) {
                $('ul.navbar-nav > li').css('background-color', 'transparent');
                $(this).css('background-color', '#c0c0c0');
            });
        });
    </script>

Here is my code:
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="website.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
        <title> Why So Serious </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1><span> Why So Serious</span></h1>
        </header>
    </body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="goodnews.html">Goodnews</a></li>
            <li><a href="sport.html">Sport</a></li>
            <li><a href="style.html">Style</a></li>
            <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</html>

CSS:
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

h1 {text-align: center;
    font-size: 600% ;
    font-style: itaic;
    background: #33ACFF ;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

/* top nav bar style and location */
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

/* top nav bar options styling */
.navbar a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar a:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.navbar .active{
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}

.navbar li{
    display: inline;
}


Do you want to make the nav bar change its background color when the cursor is down on it? If this is the case, CSS has a pseudo-element called :active. It will apply the assigned CSS to the element when it is clicked. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

document.getElementById("myDIV"); no such element, btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn"); no such elements - not sure if the javascript is at all related to the HTML - perhaps that's the issue?

Your nav goes to different pages, on each page you can have your body element with a matching ID for the buttons class. Place a class with that page, then style your css to include a <body id="goodnews"> on the good news page in your nav <a class="goodnews" href="#goodnews">Goodnews</a>, do this for each page. Then in CSS body#goodnews .navbar a.goodnews style as you will. Do this for each button in your css. No JS needed.

You need to keep track of which item is active. You can do this by setting an "active" class on an item when it's clicked. You can do that by adding an event listener to each item.
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('nav a')

navItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    item.classList.add('active')
  })
})

Once there's an active class on an element, you can select and style it with css:
a.active {
  background-color: ...
}

Seeing as we're adding the active class on click, we also need to be removing any previously added active classes. We can do this by creating a "clearActiveClass" function and calling it before we set the new active class.
function clearActiveClass () {
  navItems.forEach(item => {
    item.classList.remove('active')
  })
}

See snippet for example:


const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('nav a')

navItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    clearActiveClass()
    item.classList.add('active')
  })
})


function clearActiveClass () {
  navItems.forEach(item => {
    item.classList.remove('active')
  })
}
nav {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

a.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0);
}
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">FAQs</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>




Firstly, in your HTML, you need to include the script tags for jQuery and your JavaScript file.
@nd point I've found is that you should place your navigation inside the  tag, as  is a part of the document body.
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
    <title>Why So Serious</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1><span>Why So Serious</span></h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="goodnews.html">Goodnews</a></li>
            <li><a href="sport.html">Sport</a></li>
            <li><a href="style.html">Style</a></li>
            <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="website.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Build a script based on adding an 'active' class to the link .
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navbar ul li a').click(function (e) {
        $('.navbar ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});

Additionally, style the link in the active position.
CSS:
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 600%;
    font-style: italic;
    background: #33ACFF;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.navbar a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.navbar a.active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline;
}


You can edit your JavaScript and HTML as follows to get the desired functionality of having the navigation bar's background colour change when a link is clicked and remain active after the new page loads:
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="website.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
    <title>Why So Serious</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1><span>Why So Serious</span></h1>
    </header>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="goodnews.html">Goodnews</a></li>
            <li><a href="sport.html">Sport</a></li>
            <li><a href="style.html">Style</a></li>
            <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- OTHER HTML HERE -->
</body>
</html>

JavaScript:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var currLoc= window.location.pathname;

    // Get all links in the navbar
    var links = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar a");

    // Loop through each link
    links.forEach(function(link) {
        // Check if the link's href matches the current page URL
        if (link.getAttribute("href") === currLoc) {
            // Add 'active' class to the parent list item
            link.parentNode.classList.add("active");
        }

        // Add click event listener to each link
        link.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // Remove 'active' class from all items
            links.forEach(function(item) {
                item.parentNode.classList.remove("active");
            });

            // Add 'active' class to parent
            link.parentNode.classList.add("active");
        });
    });
});


Here's how you can do it:
The nav links in your HTML lead to different pages or paths. Since each link opens a new page, the active/opened link has to be determined on each page load. So, I'm assuming you have an HTML template/page for each path (goodnews.html, sport.html, style.html, and forum.html) in your project folder.
If not, create them in your project folder, and paste the following HTML code in each of them to see this solution working. You won't be able to see the result by running this snippet on stackoverflow because it doesn't allow multiple HTML pages here. You need to run this solution in you local dev environment by adhering to the instructions I've written above.
On each link (anchor), I've created an ID that matches the page name. Use the following HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code to change the style of the active link. There are more ways to achieve this, but this is what I could come up with, off the top of my mind.


"use strict";
/* JavaScript: */

window.onload = function () {
  const navBar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
  const path = window.location.pathname.slice(1, -5);
  path && navBar.querySelector(`#${path}`).classList.add("active");
};
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 600%;
  font-style: itaic;
  background: #33acff;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

/* top nav bar style and location */
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

/* top nav bar options styling */
.navbar a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar .active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline;
}
<!-- IMPORTANT: Paste this HTML code into all HTML pages/paths (goodnews.html, sport.html, style.html, forum.html) in your project folder: -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
    <script src="website.js" defer></script>
    <title> Why So Serious </title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1><span> Why So Serious</span></h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="goodnews.html" id="goodnews" class="nav-link">Goodnews</a></li>
            <li><a href="sport.html" id="sport" class="nav-link">Sport</a></li>
            <li><a href="style.html" id="style" class="nav-link">Style</a></li>
            <li><a href="forum.html" id="forum" class="nav-link">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>




Thanks ! What's the advantage of "use strict" for the javascript?

There are many. E.g.: In sloppy (regular) mode, certain variable types have an 'undefined' value when hoisted. But, in strict mode, you get a reference error if you try to access them before declaration. This can help you avoid bugs. There are many other advantages. You can read about them here.
Also, if this answer worked, please consider accepting it as the solution to your question.
